# AWS Connecting to instance in public subnet

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, vpc

I'm trying to SSH into a  known good instance inside a new AWS VPN 
Set up so far

Elastic IP connected to VPC instance inside public subnet 
IGW associated with subnet with CIDR 0.0.0.0/0
Security Groups set up

Does anyone have any debug tips? Does the configuration matter?
Mostly want to know how to debug and isolate issues like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your security group make sure your allowing the SSH port and also the CIDR for the inbound traffic to bind to that port.

Comment: Thanks very much user2040074 -it was the security group